# How to detect the direction of mouse wheel scrolling?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm looking for a way to detect mouse wheel scrolling inside my application.
I tried using `Listener` and its `PointerScrollEvent`, however, I don't see a way to detect the direction of the scroll, only my pointers position and such.

It would be best if I could get an integer as to, how many 'clicks' have the user scrolled.

Is there a clean method of detecting mouse wheel scrolling AND its direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pointerSignal.scrollDelta` is the property, I'm so dumb